# How to change color of value in justGage

Tags: javascript, css, html, raphael, justgage

I would like to know if there is a way to change the color and possibly the decoration of the text in the Value parameter of justGage after the gauge is created.

Ultimately, I would like to be able to change the color of the text to blue with underline so as to resemble a link.

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  You might want to try and create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to demonstrate your issue.

Comment: Please post an example @ http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In looking at the site there are examples of elements you can edit to customize your style.

GO to "Demos > Customize Style" and you will see this list:

Here's a list of all parameters you can setup your gauge with:

```
id : string container element id
title : string gauge title text
titleFontColor : string color title text
value : int value gauge is showing
valueFontColor : string color of value text
min : int minimum value
max : int maximum value
showMinMax : bool hide or display min and max values
gaugeWidthScale : float width of the gauge element
gaugeColor : string background color of gauge element
label : string text to show below value
showInnerShadow : bool whether to display inner shadow
shadowOpacity : float shadow opacity, values 0 ~ 1
shadowSize : int inner shadow size
shadowVerticalOffset : int how much is shadow offset from top
levelColors : array of strings colors of indicator, from lower to upper, in hex format
levelColorsGradient : bool use gradual or sector-based color change
labelFontColor : string color of label showing label under value
startAnimationTime : int length of initial load animation
startAnimationType : string type of initial animation (linear, >, <, <>, bounce)
refreshAnimationTime : int length of refresh animation
refreshAnimationType : string type of refresh animation (linear, >, <, <>, bounce)
```

Now, whether or not you can adjust these values AFTER the gauge is made, that I don't know. i have a feeling that you cannot do that.